# req.body is empty just like {}

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The req.body is simply {}. None of the form data is in req.body. Note that it works great in postman.

Below is the server code:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const express = require('express');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
const {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose');

var {authenticate, authenticateAdmin} = require('./middleware/authenticate');

const port = process.env.PORT;
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    var body = _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'password']);
    console.log(body)
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}`);
});
```

Below is the relevant html portion:

```
<form action="/users" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">Done</button>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Before using `_.pick`, did you print `req.body.email`?

Comment: req.body is empty, just {}

Comment: can you print `console.log(req.body.email)` ?

Comment: console.log(req.body.email) prints undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
```

You need add this line for encoded body.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to the server and it worked

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
```